# Ready to use intents & dialogs for Chatbot

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I'm using IBM Watson Conversation to build a bot. I'm looking for ready to use dialogs & intents regarding the most commonly used conversation statements.

Like: Welcome, Good Morning, Aha, Good Evening, How are you, Who are you, etc...

Actually when I used api.ai from Google, there's a default WELCOME intent, it's AMAZING. I'm looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1):

In Conversation service, you get the default "welcome" message node and another node for "anything_else" which will be executed when no other intent matches the user query. These two nodes get created for you the moment you go to the Dialogue tab of the service for the first time.

This gives you a skeleton of how you can add new nodes as per your need. Currently there aren't any other intents that Conversation service provides by default, which also makes sense in someway as everyone's need might be different.

But the service provides some default entities which are called "system entities". These are common entities like Person's name, location, currency etc that might be used in almost all sorts of chatbot scenarios. By default, these will be disabled, but you can turn them on from the "Entity" tab and click on system entities. For better designing I recommend you check this [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/intents-entities.html#planning-your-entities)